# how will set Progress bar only for button event

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am using a `updateProgress` bar in my Page on  `ProcessButton` event **Click** but it always visible in all post backs related another control events  in this Page.

when I click `cancel` Button it will be visible. on `textchanged` event of `textbox` it will be **visible**. I want see `updateProgress` will be work only on my `BtnProcess` Click event only .I have another one `button` for clear text box. also am using update Pane and ajax control on this page.

how will solve my issue. in this page i have gave Post true a text box

```
       <div class="container-fluid">  
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="well span5 center login-box">
            <div class="alert alert-info">
                    <font size="4"><b></b></font></div>                 

                <form id="form1" runat="server">                  
                    <fieldset>                        
                       <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" 
                            runat="server">
                        </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager> 

                         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pan1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>          
                      <table style="width: 100%">
                     <tr>                                                                             
                        <td align="left" colspan="2" class="style16">                            
                 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                   <ContentTemplate>                 
           <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" DisplayAfter="10" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="pan1">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div class="divWaiting">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblWait" runat="server" Text=" Your Data Is Processing... " />
                    <asp:Image ID="imgWait" runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~/Processing/progress.gif" />
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>                     
        </asp:UpdateProgress>  
      </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>                                                                             
                        <td align="right" class="style18">

                            Date</td>
                        <td align="left" class="style3">
                        <div class="input-prepend" title="Select Date" data-rel="tooltip">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate> 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                ontextchanged="txtDate_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                                <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1"
                                    runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtDate">
                                </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                                </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
                                </div>
                        </td>
                </tr>


                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                         <asp:Button ID="btnProcess" class="btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Attendance Process" Height="36px" Width="133px" onclick="btnProcess_Click" />&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                <asp:Button ID="btnclear" class="btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Clear" Height="36px" Width="91px" 
onclick="btnclear_Click" />

                            <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                            </ContentTemplate>                                       
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>                                                                             

                        <td align="left" colspan="2" style3">
                             &nbsp&nbsp 
                    <%--          <div class="alert alert-info">
                    <font="4"><b>Processing Report.</b></font>
                </div>--%>
                             <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" style="margin-left:170px;" runat="server" BackColor="#DEBA84" 
                                 BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
                                 CellSpacing="2" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                 DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" PageSize="5" 
                                 onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
                                 <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SL.No">
                                     <ItemTemplate>
                                          <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
                                     </ItemTemplate>
                                     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                          </asp:TemplateField>
                                     <asp:BoundField DataField="ProcDate" HeaderText="ProcDate" 
                                         SortExpression="ProcDate" ReadOnly="True" />
                                     <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
                                         SortExpression="Status" />
                                 </Columns>
                                 <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                                 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                 <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                 <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                                 <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                 <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
                                 <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
                                 <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
                                 <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
                             </asp:GridView>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                                                                             
                        <td align="left" style3" class="style19">

                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ManjilasConnectionString %>" 

                                SelectCommand="select Convert(varchar(10),ProcDate,126)As ProcDate,Status from ProcessingDate   order by ProcDate desc"></asp:SqlDataSource>

                        </td>
                </tr>                 
              </table>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                      <Triggers>
                       <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnProcess" />
                        </Triggers><%----%>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </div>
                        </i></span>

                </fieldset>

                </form>
                 </div>
                </div><!--/span-->
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

update `codebehind` file with this code :

```
ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
scriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(this.btnProcess);
```